# How do I increase CPU utilization for processing a dataframe in for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, optimization, geocoding

I have a dataset of about 200,000 addresses that I want to geocode (i.e., find the latitudes and longitudes of). My (simplified) code to do this is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
Latitudes = np.zeros(len(df))
Longitudes = np.zeros(len(df))

def geocode_address(address):
    ### The logic for geocoding an address
    ### and return its latitude and longitude

for i in range(len(df)):
    try:
        lat, lon = geocode_address(df.Address[i])
    except:
        lat = lon = ''
    Latitudes[i] = lat
    Longitudes[i] = lon
```

The problem is that each row (address) takes about 1-1.3 seconds to geocode, so this code will take at least a couple of days to finish running for the entire dataset. I am running this on a jupyter notebook in Windows 10. When I look at the task manager, I see that the process `jupyter.exe` **is taking only 0.3-0.7% of the CPU!** That is surprisingly low I think. Am I looking at the wrong process? If not, how do I increase the CPU utilization to at least, say, 50% for this code, so that the code can finish running in a few minutes or hours instead of taking a couple of days?

Comment: Is there a strong need for looping? Why not `apply`?

Comment: @Fourier I am actually saving (appending) the results for each chunk of 1000 records in a file, that's why I am using the for loop. But the reason I am doing this is that in case the kernel goes dead (or anything goes wrong), I can have the results so far. However, if using `apply` can finish it in minutes, then I am open to doing it. However, I don't think that would work because I am using the HERE API for the geocoding, and I think they would have placed some speed limits in the free tier (which I am using). Not to mention the monthly limit on the number of free geocodings allowed.

Comment: you need to check the python.exe instead of the jupyer.exe one and can you put your full code so that we can see if it can be improved (for loop is the probably slowest way to go)

Comment: I cannot see any relationship between using for loop and the limitation of HERE API... Whether your local machine is fast or slow, the limitation is fixed. Then it would always be better that your local machine can be faster.

Comment: @Mayeulsgc Updated the question details with my full code.

Comment: @Sraw I have updated the question details with my full code. I don't know how many addresses the API allows to geocode in 1 second. But if that number is low (like 1 address per second for example), it would keep the overall run time of the code high, isn't it?

Comment: if the run limit is max 1 per sec you will have at least 55h for your code. Therefore 2 possibilities while staying without paying, first, did you ensure that all addresses were unique ? Second can you create several accounts and make your code jungle between the accounts ?

Comment: @Mayeulsgc Yes, I ensured all addresses are unique. About creating multiple accounts, I would have thought of making a new account if the current one's free tier limit got exhausted (which is 250,000 geoencodings per month). But since I have 200,000 addresses, I did not think about it. But since the CPU is not getting used fully, I am ok to create, say, 10 accounts and partition the data into 10 parts, and run 10 different notebooks for each part. As long as that does not decrease the speed of geocoding each address, I am fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're barking at the wrong tree. Your code is not CPU-bound, it's IO-bound (there's no intensive computation going on, most of the time is spent doing HTTP requests).

The canonical solution to such problems is parallelization (you may want to have a look at the `multiprocessing`  module), and by itself it's quite easy to implement here since - BUT you'll still have to deal with your geocoding API rate limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue based on Bruno's advice, by partitioning the data into 10 subsets of 20k rows each. Then I ran 10 jupyter notebooks with the same code on each of the partitions. This is basically "stone age parallel processing", but it did solve the issue in a simple way - the whole job finished in about 5 hours.

The key thing to keep in mind though is to notice how much of the CPU is being taken by each notebook - in my case, it was about 1%. So, theoretically, I could have partitioned the data into, say, 50 parts and the whole task would have finished in about an hour. However, if each notebook was taking, say, 10% of the CPU, then at max I would have partitioned the data into 6-7 parts, as I would like to keep at least 30-40% of the CPU for other apps and processes.

I would love to know if there's a way to automate this process - i.e., to find what's the max number of partitions such that when running the same notebook on each of those partitions, the total CPU usage does not exceed a specified threshold. And then, of course, partition the data and run the code on each of them.

Comment: If that's a general question, you should post it as a question, not as an answer to your own question (hint: SO is _not_ a forum, it's a QA based technical knowledge base). Just note that with nowadays multicore processors, CPU usage is much less of an issue - specially for short tasks that are _not_ CPU-bound. Your ethernet connection will probably be the first bottleneck here...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, I will post it as a separate question if I need to use `multiprocessing` someday and I can't do it myself even after researching about it. I just wanted to answer my question to help someone who might be having the same issue, and doesn't want to, or need to, complicate the solution by using `multiprocessing`.